# Why won't the ColdFusion ODBC package install?

Tags: coldfusion, odbc, datasource, windows-server-2019

I've successfully set up an ODBC datasource in Windows under "ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)," but I can't set up a ColdFusion datasource that connects to it until I have the ColdFusion ODBC package installed and running.

Environment details:

- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
- ColdFusion 2021 Update 12
- Java JDK 11.0.21 (64-bit)

When I attempt to install the ODBC package using the command prompt, I get the following:

[image]

When I attempt to install the ODBC package using the ColdFusion admin interface, this blue circle spins for several minutes:

[image]

Eventually, I receive this error:

[image]

If you know what's causing these failures, or if you're aware of another way to install ColdFusion packages, perhaps offline and manually, I would appreciate knowing. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a dedicated user on that server with strict permissions related to the ColdFusion server? Does that user have access to alter or access the folders where that package will be installed? Check the ACF 2021 Lockdown Guide to see if user permissions need to be adjusted. https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/cc/us/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf-starter-kits/coldfusion-2021-lockdown-guide-1.1.pdf